# In "The Wolf's Hour", why did Michael Gallatin have to catch a train to escape the forest?

Tags: the-wolfs-hour

I read 1989's *[The Wolf's Hour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wolf%27s_Hour)* by Robert R. McCammon. It was an interesting take on the werewolf tale.

However, I seem to have gotten lost in one of the character's flashbacks somewhere along the line. I don't understand why he had to catch a train to get away from the forest. It was a major concern in the book.

What prevented him from just walking away?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Michael's deal with the train was that he had to have the confidence in himself to get past it as it was coming before he could leave the forest as the Wolf. One of the other wolves wanted to do the same and did *not* make it.